# Line/word wrapping in revision history and responses tab (and probably other places)

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, information-display, responses

> [image]

and

> [image]
>   ([Link](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/1331/revisions))

I just noticed that change. I didn't find new reports under [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Note the names and badge count in the first screenshot, and the badge count in the second one.

PS I can't link to the responses tab as it shows only to the profile owner.

Comment: Able to reproduce on Chrome 79 on Windows.

Comment: ymb1, to link to the responses tab use this URL: [https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses) - replace name and # with "current" (doesn't always work, but it does in this case).

Comment: The problem now appears for Stack Overflow with revision "ev 2020.1.21.35842".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a fix for this in the queue for deployment, but this being Friday night, it probably won't happen till Monday.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Could this be the same "bug": https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8479/display-comments-in-vertical-position

Comment: @rene Yeah, it's the same thing. `Responses` is the only tab that renders usercards, so every subtab under it was affected in the same way.

Comment: It **was** fixed for the user card in the revision history (the example in the question), but it's back again to two lines. Do I submit a new post, or does this comment suffice? Thanks Adam.

Comment: @ymb1 The width of that column is fixed, so it *will* wrap at some point for longer user names or badge counts. If you're seeing something stranger than that, link me to a screenshot, please.